# Error : Still Getting Error after setting allowLargeResults to true in job configuration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery

I have written bigquery in my code.
I want to fetch larger result.

I also set the propertie **allowLargeResult:true** , But Still i am getting the Error : **Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration. For more information, see http
s://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors**

Here is my Node.js Code :

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var bigquery = google.bigquery('v2');

var authClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    'arjun-dev@mybank-bigquery.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    'keyA.pem',
    null, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery']);

var request2 = {
    projectId: 'project-bank',
    jobId:'job_LHMRhoUfM038QA4jPZHaOESI3Uo',
    startIndex: 0,
    maxResults: 100000,
    timeoutMs: 10000,
    configuration:{
        allowLargeResults: true
    },      
    auth: authClient
};

var list1 = bigquery.jobs.getQueryResults(request2, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("### 2 " + err);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result);
    }
});
```

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result might be too large to return and you are missing the destination table as that is mandatory when you set `allowLargeResults` true, as you cannot return large result instead you need to write to a destination table. If you later want to get the data, you need to export the table to GCS and then download from GCS.

**Returning large query results**

Normally, queries have a maximum response size 128 MB compressed. If you plan to run a query that might return larger results, you can set `allowLargeResults` to true in your job configuration.

Queries that return large results take longer to execute, even if the result set is small, and are subject to additional limitations:

- You must specify a destination table.
- You can't specify a top-level ORDER BY, TOP or LIMIT clause. Doing so negates the benefit of using allowLargeResults, because the query output can no longer be computed in parallel.
- Window functions can return large query results only if used in conjunction with a PARTITION BY clause.

Comment: yes , i am fetching 8 millions of records..When i specifying my DESTINATION TABLE the result will go their...so i have to again query on destination table.. is it right. ?

Comment: you need either to paginate the table, or export the table as file as mentioned

Comment: check the library you are using, they might have examples for pagination